# Reverse Search (CTRL + R) no longer searching in .zsh_history

Tags: zsh, command-history

Until recently I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search for recent commands in my terminal which uses the `zsh` shell. The search included commands from previous sessions which were saved in my `~/.zsh_history` file.

Now when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> it only searches commands from the current terminal session and does not search in the `~/.zsh_history` file. I have also notices that the `~/.zsh_history` file is no longer being updated.

How do I fix this?

I have tried adding the following to my `.zshrc` file but it has made no difference:

```
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
HISTSIZE=10000  # Save most-recent 1000 lines
SAVEHIST=10000  # Save most-recent 1000 lines

bindkey -v
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your `.zshrc` to your question. It's impossible to solve without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with fzf integration which was fixed recently in an update to fzf. You can find the relevant issue here:

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2943

You simply need to update to version 0.33.0 or later.